# How can I get the Laravel 7 Homestead database snapshots working?

Tags: laravel, homestead, lvm

I've enjoyed Homestead for years and today noticed a very appealing feature that I've never used before.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#database-snapshots says:

> Homestead supports freezing the state of MySQL and MariaDB databases
>   and branching between them using Logical MySQL Manager. For example,
>   imagine working on a site with a multi-gigabyte database. You can
>   import the database and take a snapshot. After doing some work and
>   creating some test content locally, you may quickly restore back to
>   the original state.
>
> ...
>
> A common workflow looks like the following:
>
> 1. Import a database into the default `master` lmm branch.
> 2. Save a snapshot
>      of the unchanged database using `sudo lmm branch prod-YYYY-MM-DD`.
> 3. Modify the database.
> 4. Run `sudo lmm merge prod-YYYY-MM-DD` to undo all
>      changes.
> 5. Run `sudo lmm delete <branch>` to delete unneeded branches.

This tool sounds really useful, but I'm having trouble following those instructions. Here is what I've tried and the results:

```
sudo lmm status
Active snapshot:

Database snapshots:
  master

2.70% used by MySQL databases.
sudo lmm branch beforeImports
df: '': No such file or directory
  Logical volume name "" is invalid.
  Run `lvcreate --help' for more information.
mount: /homestead-vg/beforeImports: special device /dev/homestead-vg/mysql-beforeImports does not exist.
mount: /homestead-vg/beforeImports: special device /dev/homestead-vg/mysql-beforeImports does not exist.
mount: /homestead-vg/prod-YYYY-MM-DD: special device /dev/homestead-vg/mysql-prod-YYYY-MM-DD does not exist.
mount: /homestead-vg/beforeImports: special device /dev/homestead-vg/mysql-beforeImports does not exist.
sudo lmm checkout master
is the currently active database.
Setting /homestead-vg/master as the active database.
rm: cannot remove '/var/lib/mysql': Is a directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/lib/mysql/master': File exists
```

I'm using: Windows 10, Vagrant 2.2.7, Virtualbox 6.1.2, Homestead v10.2.0.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I looked at https://github.com/Lullabot/lmm/blob/ubuntu-18.04/functions.sh#L5 (which I think is what Homestead is using), and then I ran `` sudo echo `readlink `` `` /var/lib/mysql` ``, and it printed a blank line. But `sudo ls -lah /var/lib/mysql` shows lots of files. I clearly don't know what I'm doing and would appreciate any help.

P.P.S. I also see https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1112 but do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug that prevented LMM from working with MySQL 8: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1383